# printing the DOM array through dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, node.js, polymer

I have one Array **graphData**. Now I want to use dom-repeat to print it.

```
<template is='dom-repeat' items='{{internalgraphData}}'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{item.asset}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.percentage}}%</td>
                            <td>{{item.investment}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.currentvalue}}</td>
                            <td class="u-value-align"><span class="red-text darken-4">{{item.gain}}</span></td>
                            <td><img src="../images/arrow-red.png"></td>
                            <td class="black-text"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn white blue-text back" href="equity.html">Select</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
```

My json is as below... I tried to create the dom-repeat structure with below tag-value "internalgraphData"
I printed internalgraphData, it looks I successfully transferred the data from json to local tag-value structure "internalgraphData"

```
 Polymer({  is: 'my-menu',
........
ready : function(graphid,graphData) {
                            this.graphData = [
                                ['Equity', 50,25000,37000,240],
                                ['Bonds', 35,12500,10000,-480],
                                ['Alternates',5, 2000,2000,340],
                                ['Cash',10,1000,1000,-140]
                            ];

                            if (this.graphData.length > 0)
                            {
                                for(i = 0; i< this.graphData.length; i++)
                                {
                                    this.internalgraphData.push({
                                        "asset" : this.graphData[i][0],
                                        "percentage" : this.graphData[i][1],
                                        "investment" : this.graphData[i][2],
                                        "currentvalue" : this.graphData[i][3],
                                        "gain" : this.graphData[i][4]

                                    }); 
                                }
```

But I see that the dom-repeat is not printing .
Could anyone help how can we achieve that?

NOTE: If I add the tag-value explicitly... the table is coming...

```
this.internalgraphData = [
                        /*['Equity', 50,25000,37000,240],
                        ['Bonds', 35,12500,10000,-480],
                        ['Alternates',5, 2000,2000,340],
                        ['Cash',10,1000,1000,-140]*/

                        {asset: 'Equity', percentage: 50, investment: 25000, currentvalue: 37000, gain: 240 },
                        {asset: 'Equity', percentage: 35, investment: 12500, currentvalue: 10000, gain: -480 },
                        {asset: 'Equity', percentage: 5,  investment: 2000, currentvalue: 2000, gain: 340 },
                        {asset: 'Equity', percentage: 10, investment: 1000, currentvalue: 1000, gain: -140 }
                    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.internalgraphData.push({});
```

above operations in loop doesn't reflect in polymer data-change.Below is the recommended way to object in array.

**`this.push('internalgraphData', {title:'hey'});`**
if you can't do this way. please use below way

```
this.updatedgraphData  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.internalgraphData ));
```

use dom-repeat over `***updatedgraphData***`